# Arzela Ascoli variation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, bounded-variation

I am trying to prove the following variation of the Arzel-Ascoli theorem:

Let $(f_n)n$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ whose derivatives are uniformly bounded and there is an $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $(f_n(x_0))_n$ is bounded in $R$. Prove that $f_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.
k
I can prove that the sequence $f_n$ is equicontinuous but I am not sure how to use the fact that it is bounded at one point. It mean it is just a sequence of real numbers which is bounded thus we can find a converging subsequence $f_{n_k}(x_0)$
but how to continue for the uniform convergence part?

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: The derivatives are uniformly bounded, and the sequence is bounded in one point - can you use it to show the whole family is uniformly bounded on the interval?

Comment: I think I can show the fam. is pointwise bounded. I don't see  how to prove it is unif. bounded.

Comment: Hint: use mean value theorem and *uniform* bound on the derivatives.

Comment: I can prove that using the MVT we have that the sequence is equicontinuous and point-wise bounded thus exactly the conditions we need to apply AA Theorem.

Comment: Yes, exactly :) (I assume you mean "uniformly bounded")

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for the hint!